# Is it possible to "derive" gradient descent using Lagrangian multipliers?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I'm thinking about this in 1-dimension but would have thought this will generalise fairly trivially to higher dimensions.

If we're currently at $x=x_{1}$, and we have relatively easy access to $f(x_{1})$ and $f'(x_{1})$, we might argue that

$f(x_{1} + \epsilon)\simeq f(x_{1}) + f'(x_{1})\epsilon $

provided
$\epsilon ^{2} < \delta$

Thus I would hoping to derive that the $\epsilon$ which max/minimises $f(x_{1}+\epsilon)$ wrt $\epsilon$, subject to the constraint $\epsilon ^{2} <\delta$, is given by the well-known gradient-descent/ascent answer which would be $\epsilon = \pm\delta \frac{f'(x_{1})}{|f'(x_{1})|}$

I was hoping this would drop out by differentiating

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon} \left(f(x_{1}) + f'(x_{1})\epsilon -\lambda (\epsilon ^{2} - \delta)\right)$

But I just get that $f'(x_{1})-2\lambda \epsilon=0$ and I'm not sure how eliminate $\lambda$.

I assume that two solutions should drop out, the maximum increase and decrease.

The above is trying to derive an intuitive and well-known result, but what about if I had relatively easy access to higher derivatives, then the result is not so obvious. I would have thought that if I could solve the above, then I could take this one step further and minimise

$f(x_{1}) + f'(x_{1})\epsilon + \frac{1}{2!}f''(x_{1})\epsilon^{2}$

subject to $|\epsilon ^{3}| < \delta$

but I'll run into the same problem of a solution for $\epsilon$ in terms of a $\lambda$ that I don't know how to eliminate.

Am I missing something in the calculation or is this method flawed?

Comment: You are minimizing a linear function over an interval and so the infimum occurs at an endpoint of the interval. To make things precise let us fix $\delta>0$, define the constant $a=f'(x_1)$, and make the desired interval compact (so we change the requirement $\epsilon^2<\delta$ to the requirement $\epsilon^2\leq \delta$). Using $\epsilon$ as the decision variable, we minimize $a\epsilon$ subject to $-\sqrt{\delta}\leq \epsilon \leq \sqrt{\delta}$. A minimizer is $$\epsilon^*=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{\delta} & \mbox{if $a\leq 0$} \\ -\sqrt{\delta} &\mbox{ if $a>0$} \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: In general, if you are minimizing a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ over an interval $x \in [a,b]$ then you do not need Lagrange multipliers, you look at critical points of the interval (endpoints; points of zero derivative; points where the derivative does not exist).

Comment: yes, in this simple case I get that you don't need Lagrangian Multipliers or anything fancy, it's clearly true by inspection. But I wanted to figure out the calculation for the simple case before going to second order where it's not longer the case that the solution must lie on the boundary

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Considering $\epsilon^2<\delta$ as $\epsilon^2-\delta+s^2=0$ we have

$$
L(\epsilon,\lambda,s) = f'\epsilon -\lambda(\epsilon^2-\delta+s^2)
$$

then

$$
\nabla L = 0 = 
\cases{f'-2\lambda\epsilon\\
\epsilon^2-\delta+s^2\\
\lambda s\\
}
$$

but $\epsilon = \frac 12\frac{f'}{\lambda}$ and after substitution onto the restriction we have

$$
\left(\frac 12\frac{f'}{\lambda}\right)^2-\delta+s^2=0
$$

so we have

$$
\lambda = \pm\frac 12\frac{|f'|}{\sqrt{\delta-s^2}}
$$

hence we have

$$
f'\mp \frac{|f'|}{\sqrt{\delta-s^2}}\epsilon = 0
$$

or

$$
\epsilon = \pm \sqrt{\delta-s^2}\frac{f'}{|f'|}
$$

now if the restriction is actuating ($s=0$) we have

$$
\epsilon = \pm \sqrt{\delta}\frac{f'}{|f'|}
$$

Comment: Thanks for this, I think there's a small error in here where in the equation for $\lambda$, you didn't take the route of $\frac{1}{4}$, meaning the final answer has a surplus 2. 

Other than that, was wondering whether you could flesh out the part where you say "if the restriction is actuating", I can't say I fully follow (I suspect it's also fairly key to what I was trying to do next, which is the same calculation if you expand the Taylor series to second order)

Comment: Thanks for notifying me of the mistake now fixed. Regarding the actuating restriction, we were using an equivalent representation; $\epsilon^2-\delta+s^2=0$ instead of $\epsilon^2\le \delta$. In this context, if $s=0$ means $\epsilon^2=\delta$ so the restriction is actuating otherwise $\lambda = 0$.